# acpi package has zero elements CentOS 7 boot error

Tags: linux, centos, centos7, memory, boot

I hope I asked this in the right StackExchange site, didn't knew where to post.

I have this boot error (attached), I can't understand much from it, ***acpi package has zero elements*** , etc.

I had Centos 7.9 clean installed on a computer with AMD Ryzen 5 3600 CPU, then moved the SSD in another computer, same model motherboard, different CPU (Ryzen 7 1700).

Motherboard didn't support this different CPU, I made a headless bios update without CPU or ram installed, using a motherboard function.

After bios update, I got video signal and it booted, but after a while I seen it crash once, then two times during boot, I got this attached error.

**Does this indicate a CPU compatibility with motherboard ?** CPU is not listed on motherboard supported CPU list.

**Or can I get these from taking the installed OS drive and putting it in different computer ?** (I thought Linux is flexible regarding this).

Ram is 64GB (4x16GB) 3200Mhz and I activate a XMP default profile in order to see 3200Mhz in bios.

**Could the XMP profile cause this ?**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I advice you to start in rescue mode and access into mono user mode, this will give you the chance to extract the most value info from this server, after this you can build a new machine but based now on CentOS 8 which is more compatible with Ryzen CPUs.

As a work around, once you got acces in mono user mode and already make a backup of all your information, could you please check the status of this acpi=(on or off) the path for this is on /boot/grub2/grub.cfg and try to reverse it from the actual state.